# Maven dependency not getting updated with LATEST version

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, version

I'm using intelij. I have multiple maven projects.
I deployed new version of maven Project_1, in the logs intelij showed version like this 1.0.0-20170331.023320-3.jar

Then in other Project_2 in pom file at  I set the version of Project_1 as LATEST and run install. And in the logs intelij shows that 1.0.0-20170330-253 version was downloaded. It has different timestamp and when I'm checking the file in the external libraries, it doesn't contain my recent changes.

Please, advise, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Those versions you are giving are SNAPSHOT's...so I don't understand your problem here? Show your pom file...

Comment: The version `LATEST` is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore furthermore if you simply use `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and using `mvn -U ...` maven will get the latest of the SNAPSHOT's availabe...or your can change your update policy in your settings.xml file...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, thank you for the answers! You are right, it worked after I changed LATEST to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to "Reimport all maven projects" in IntelliJ which will redownload the dependencies
Right click on the Project -> select Maven -> Click Reimport

Comment: I did that, it didn't help

Comment: Is the new version `1.0.0-20170331.023320-3.jar` available at the central repository(like nexus or something like that) which Project_2 is using?

Comment: `Reimport` then `mvn clean install`  then Build should help to get around this issue. In IntelliJ you can Build -> Rebuild project

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that, I went to the nexus and searched there by group id and artifact id and didn't find anything.
Also in the logs it says that first project uploads to https://artifactory... and second project downloads from nexus

Comment: where is 1.0.0-20170331.023320-3.jar created and available?

Comment: I've just tried how you advised - did Reimport and then run mvn clean install. It didn't help :(

Comment: then it seems `LATEST` is not really replacing it with new version.

Comment: hey, @vlaxmi, so once I changed LATEST to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, it worked! :) thank you for the help one more time :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First Please use mvn command line like **mvn compile** to find the problem.
2. Set the version to 1.0.0-**SNAPSHOT** not Latest, if you set the version to snapshot, if you using **mvn compile** command, I will check the dependency for the latest one in the maven repo. If you are using Intellij try to reimport the maven project.

Comment: Thanks, @xiaojieaa! You were right, it worked after I changed LATEST to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.